# Why is Elmah MVC logging differently locally and on live server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, elmah

i have a ASP.NET C# MVC site using Elmah MVC.

I notice some exceptions are logged on the live server that are not logged on my dev machine, though the web.configs are the same.

I raise a custom exception, and on my controller.onexception method i set filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true.

On my local PC these exceptions are not logged, but on my server that are!

I would like to have them not logged on the server, or just figure out why the 2 PCs don't behave the same.

Here's my OnException method:

```
    [NonAction]
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        ActionResult result = null;
        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;

        UCSException ex2 = ex as UCSException;
        if (ex2 != null)
        {
            switch (ex2.ErrorCode){
                case UCSException.ErrorCodes.CompanyNotValid:
                    result = RedirectToAction("index", globals.ControllerNameCompany); 
                    break;

                //etc... (snipped for brevity)
                }                 
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
```

EDIT:
When i leave filterContext.ExceptionHandled as False, i get the 500 error page and the exception is logged locally.  This is how i expected filterContext.ExceptionHandled to behave, but the live server logs the exception either way.

Comment: Check your elmah settings in the config files to make sure they match. Also on the dev server is there anything potentially setup that would prevent an exception from bubbling up to the global exception handler?

Comment: I did a compare on the web.configs and they are identical apart from DB connection strings.

Comment: I can't think of anything that would stop exceptions locally.  I've tried it with VS loaded and closed, and in a VS debug session and it behaves the same way, so VS isn't handling anything.

Comment: I just tried leaving filterContext.ExceptionHandled = false.  I get the 500 error page, and the error is logged locally.

Comment: Is the production version being served under a different site in IIS?

Comment: Would be interesting to deploy both a debug and a release build to a local IIS to see the differences there.

Comment: @PaulSwetz locally I'm using windows 10 with IIS 10 (not express).  The server is win2008R2 and IIS 7.5, so that's a difference, maybe their pipeline is in a different order?  I also checked the asp.net error page and IIS error page settings and they are the same.

Comment: @ThomasArdal I check my config and I'm using a debug build on both.  I just tried a release build locally, but that didn't change anything.